# how to implement pagination based on upper and lower limit on recyclerview

Tags: android, pagination

I'm working with recycler view and i am working on social module like facebook and want to implement Pagination on recycler view This is my method defination

** public void getUserSharedTimeline(int userId, int lowerLimit,int upperLimit )**

Now first time I send 0 to 10 to server and get ten records. and then I call it like this.

```html
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                getUserSharedTimeline(Utilities.UserTypeId,totalItemsCount,totalItemsCount+10);
            }
        });
```

On first call

1. it works and get me 10 to 20 records
2. Then on second call it gets 20 to 21 records
3. and after that it's stop scrolling and do not load more data even records are more than thousand.
4. The pagination is also done on server side and I can't request more than 10 records at a time.

Here is my class for pagination. I checked many tutorials but in vain. Please help  me in this issue.

```html
package com.intelmanager.ithash.intelmanager.ui;


import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;
import android.widget.AbsListView;

public abstract class EndlessScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 10;
    // The current offset index of data you have loaded
    private int currentPage = 0;
    // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private boolean loading = true;
    // Sets the starting page index
    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public EndlessScrollListener(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(GridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
    }

    public EndlessScrollListener(StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
    }

    public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
        int maxSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
            else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return maxSize;
    }

    // This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
    // We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
    // but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0;
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

        if (mLayoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
            int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
            // get maximum element within the list
            lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
        } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        }

        // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
        // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                this.loading = true;
            }
        }
        // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
        // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
        // number and total item count.
        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        }

        // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
        // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
        // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
        // threshold should reflect how many total columns there are too
        if (!loading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {
            currentPage++;
            onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount);

}
```

Comment: sorry, I have the same problem. Do you have a solution? How to solve?